# Is Advanced Boot Options Same as Advanced Startup Options?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, recovery-console

Is Advanced Boot Options exactly same as Advanced Startup Options?

Or is Advanced Boot Options only available in Windows 7 and it's replaced by Advanced Startup Options later on in Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Advanced Boot Options menu is a selectable list of Windows startup modes and troubleshooting tools. It was replaced by **Startup Settings** (Troubleshoot> Advanced Options>Startup Settings) in windows 8, Startup Settings is a part of Advanced Startup Options.
Advanced Startup Options is a centralized menu of recovery, repair, and troubleshooting tools in Windows 8 and Windows 10. It replaced the **System Recovery Options menu** (**Repair your computer** in Advanced Boot Options) available in Windows7.